# Linux: create multivolume tape encrypted with ssl..is possible?

Tags: tar, encryption, ssl, tape

I want to backup my data on tapes.

I had a Ultrium LTO6

Make an encrypted backup with SINGLE tape works fine

```
tar cpMf - /home/ | openssl enc -e -aes128 -salt -pass file:file.password |(pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > /dev/st0)
```

But how to do with multiple tapes when a lot of data is more than tape size?

I have tried this(1G is for testing..)

```
tar cMpf - --tape-length=1G --blocking-factor 2048 -X /etc/file.exclude  /home| openssl enc -e -aes256 -salt -pass file:pass.txt -out /dev/st0
```

works and ask for other tapes,I put as answer

```
n /dev/st0
```

But when I read the tapes,first tapes is ok

```
enc -d -aes256 -pass file:pass.txt -in /dev/st0 | tar Mtvf -
```

works(I can see list of files) and ask for other tapes,I put as answer

```
n /dev/st0
```

And give error..like pass is wrong :(

Some suggestion for good encryption mutltiple tapes?

p.s=hw encryption with stenc give me error.

Comment: Are you aware that with CBC mode that if a single byte on the tape gets corrupted, the entirely remainder of the tape will be unreadable? And if run across multiple tapes (like it appears you're trying to do), the rest of the tape set? Also, is there a reason you're rolling your own instead of using an existing backup system with encryption (e.g., at least Bacula and Bareos have it).

Comment: BTW: You might want to ask how to get the hardware encryption working. Or point the to the question where you already did...

Comment: Don't write out a single multi-TB tar file that spans tapes. It isn't going to be fun trying to restore one file on tape 3. It'll take 10 hours to read through the first two tapes. Instead, write out tar files that are no more than, say, 12GB each. You can seek to any tar file pretty quickly and read it in in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: hw encryption give me this error tenc -f /dev/nst0 -e on -k /root/myaes.key 
Provided key length is 256 bits.
Key checksum is ffffd10b.
Turning on encryption on device '/dev/nst0'...
Sense Code:              Illegal Request (0x05)
 ASC:                    0x26
 ASCQ:                   0x00
 Additional data:        0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Error: Turning encryption on for '/dev/nst0' failed!
Usage: stenc --version | -g <length> -k <file> [-kd <description>] | -f <device> [--detail] [-e <on/mixed/rawread/off> [-k <file>] [-kd <description>] [-a <index>] [--protect | ...

Comment: Have you looked at a proper backup tool like Amanda (http://amanda.org) or Bareos (https://www.bareos.org/en/)?  Most backup software these days automatically handles spanning tapes and supports encryption.  Such options take a bit more effort to set up initially, but tend to be easier to get support for, and are also usually much more reliable.

Comment: yes but I prefer tar,now I will take a look to amanda

Comment: The multi volume support in `gtar` is unreliable. Maybe this is why people prefer amanda. If you like a tar implementation with reliable multi volume support, use `star`.